# Change directory working directory in shell script

Tags: shell-script, rhel

I am trying to write a simple shell script, 
which will change the directory to the shell script directory and echo it.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd '/explicit/path/to/script'
cd $(dirname $0)
echo $(dirname $0)
```

The output indeed is always, even if I use an explicite cd to the script dir.

```
/bin
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: run it from within home dir: `. /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: you're sourcing the script, not executing it.  `$0` is probably `/bin/bash` (i.e. your current command-line shell) from the sourced script's POV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the script instead of sourcing it:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

(without `.`).

When you run

```
. /path/to/script.sh
```

`$0` is your current shell, which is presumably in `/bin` (hence the behaviour you're seeing). Note that it needn't be `/bin/bash`, the shebang doesn't have any effect when sourcing a script.

[Lucas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/88313/lucas)' other points are valid, you should use quotes and just run `dirname` directly, without `echo`.

Comment: If the OP wants to change to that directory, he may want to call the script with `cd "$(/path/to/script)"` - however, it must be executed instead of sourced; and an executed script runs in an own subshell and hence cannot change the directory of the calling shell. There are other approaches to do so better (aliases, functions, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$0` points to the shell script that you execute itself.  So if you have a file in that contains this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0"
```

and copy it to `/bin/my-script` and to `~/somewhere/my-script-2`, make both copies executable you can observe this behavior (I assume `/bin` is in your `$PATH`):

```
$ my-script
/bin/my-script
$ ~/somewhere/my-script-2
/home/luc/somewhere/my-script-2
$ cd
$ somewhere/my-script-2
somewhere/my-script-2
$ ../../bin/my-script
../../bin/my-script
$ cd /bin
$ ./my-script
./my-script
```

and so on.

In an interactive shell `$0` points to the shell you execute and that is most probably in `/bin`.  So if you source the above shell scripts you will always see the path to your shell interpreter: `/bin/bash` .  For this the two script don't have to be executable:

```
$ . my-script
/bin/bash
$ . ~/somewhere/my-script-2
/bin/bash
$ cd
$ . somewhere/my-script-2
/bin/bash
$ . ../../bin/my-script
/bin/bash
$ cd /bin
$ . ./my-script
/bin/bash
```

The reason is that a sourced script is executed in the same process that sources it and `$0` is not changed (`$@` is updated though).

If `dirname "$0"` prints `/bin` for you, that just means the file you execute is in `/bin` or you are running `dirname` from a interactive session or a sourced script and the interpreter you use is in `/bin`.

Some other points:

- You don't need to do `echo "$(dirname "$0")"`, `dirname "$0"` will do the same.
- Use `pwd` the get the *current* working directory.
- Put quotes around `$0` and command substitution as you might run into problems otherwise.  Try something like `cd $(echo a b c)` to see the problem.